# Is source code visible to users accessing a web-based software?

Tags: security

Is software source code visible to users accessing web-based software? i.e. does anyone who has access to my URL have access to the software source code (assuming that URL is where the software is run)?

What about software that requires a user to login. Do all users with login credentials have access to the software source code (assuming their user has access to the full software).

If source code is normally visible - are there any security measures that can be taken to avoid theft?

EDIT: By software source code I meant everything comprehensively (server-side, client-side etc.)

Comment: Define: "source code". Is HTML and CSS considered source-code worthy of "protection"?

Answer (score 2):

### Short and general answers:

- For program code that executes on the web-server: **No**, end-users cannot see this code at all.
- For program code that executes in the web-browser (namely HTML, CSS and JavaScript): **Yes**, end users *have* to have access to this code for the browser to run it. The WWW does not support any kind of DRM.

### Exceptions to those answers:

- If the server-side code is "on-premises" then the sysadmin of the on-prem hardware can easily peek around the server-side code.

  - If it's a strictly interpreted code, like PHP or Classic ASP then yes, the source-code is visible.
  - If it's native compiled code (e.g. CGI) then no (unless the user can read assembly)
  - If it's VM code like C# (ASP.NET) or Java (JSP, Tomcat, etc) then the code can be easily decompiled.
- Server-side code can be *unintentionally* exposed in "cloud" (not on-prem installs):

  - Error messages often show a few lines of source-code where an error occurred.
  - A vulnerability may expose the raw filesystem of your application to users.
- Client-side code can still be obfuscated.

  - This is often just a consequence of minifying, but you can intentionally obfuscate JavaScript. You cannot obfuscate HTML and CSS.
- "Hybrid" JavaScript that's used for both server-side execution with Node.JS and client-side execution will obviously be exposed, but this shouldn't be considered a security risk unless you somehow embed secrets in those scripts.

Comment: Thank you! I do not have a technical background so bear with me. 

As I understand - it is dependent on the specific set-up however client-side code is more difficult to hide. 

If the question is whether someone can steal software easily - does client-side code have a significant impact? More specifically - if you quantify/compare the work involved in building online software generally - is there an average percentage of cost/time attributed to client-side compared to server-side or the software as a whole? Is client-side the majority, minority or equal? Or does this vary considerably?

Comment: @walsingham97 It varies considerably.